# c printing too many chars

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

I'm trying to print out a memory address backwards like in a little endian machine, but for some reason my program is outputting both char arrays in my program.

```
char address[8];
char result[16];
scanf("%s", address);
int x = 1;
for(x; x<5; x++)
{
int y = 4*x;
int z = 8 - 2*x;
result[y-4] = '\\';
result[y-3] = 'x';
result[y-2] = address[z];
result[y-1] = address[z+1];
}
printf("%s", result);
```

for example, if I input "12345678" it outputs `"\x78\x56\x34\x1212345678"`
I want the `"\x78\x56\x34\x12"`, but I don't understand why the `"12345678"` is also printed.

Comment: Where is the [`'\0'`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)?

Comment: I would recommend you to read more about strings in C and how they work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to terminate the string. In fact, your array is to small for the terminator, you need it to be 17 characters, then do `result[16] = '\0';`.

---

Oh, and you have an out-of-bound error in your code as well, as if you enter 8 characters for the input then `scanf` will write 9 characters to the 8-character array.

Comment: @MarounMaroun As `x` is initialized to `1` right before the loop, I don't see why it would not work.

Comment: @MarounMaroun It is kind of unusual to not put the initialization in the actual `for` statement, but then the whole loop is kind of convoluted and not very straight forward. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
%s //
```

in C %s expects a pointer to a string, unlike %d or %c(these expect variables with integers or characters), so your pointer must be null terminated, so the program knows where in memory it must stop printing, or else your are printing random stuff in memory